# Usage of tracking signal as a metric when number of forecasts is low

Tags: time-series, model-evaluation, metric

Suppose Tracking Signal (TS) is used as a metric to evaluate the quality of a forecast.

Let `a` be the ground truth value and `f` be the forecasted value,

[image]

Assuming that forecast errors are normally distributed, TS < -3.75 or TS > 3.75 implies a bias in the forecast at a 3 sigma level. However, when there is persistent under/over forecast for all `n` predictions, TS will not exceed +/- `n`. If the number of forecasts is small (n<=3), TS will never exceed the TS < -3.75 or TS > 3.75 threshold. (For example, TS = 3 < 3.75 when ground truth is [100, 100, 100] and predicted is [1000, 101, 123])

In this case, how do we interpret and rationalize the TS of such a forecast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of a tracking signal is to determine whether there is significant and persistent over/under forecasting.

If you only have 3 data points, all of which are over-predicted then it's hard to argue that that constitutes a 'persistent' bias at over 3 sigma significance.

So in summary, the output of the formula is correct. For your example, TS equals 3, which means the forecasts are biased, just not at a 3 sigma significance.